# Call a phone number from a UILabel with UITapGestureRecognizer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want the user to be able to tap on a phone number and call it directly. I have 3 different numbers for each person (private, mobile and work) and 3 different labels for this. 
Now if I tap on the first or second label nothing happens, and when I tap on the third label (work) it calls the action form the first label (private).

so my **first question**: What did I wrong that it doesnt recognize the sender I tapped?

**second question**: What do I have to write in the function didTapPhoneNumber as an if statement?

```
    phoneNumberPrivate2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    phoneNumberMobile2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    phoneNumberWork2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTapPhoneNumber(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    phoneNumberPrivate2.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    phoneNumberMobile2.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    phoneNumberWork2.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

//call me maybe
@objc func didTapPhoneNumber(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("success")

    let privateCall = phoneNumberPrivate2.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
    let mobileCall = phoneNumberMobile2.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
    let workCall = phoneNumberWork2.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)

    if sender == phoneNumberPrivate2 {
        print("you tapped label \(self.phoneNumberPrivate2)")
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(String(describing: privateCall))") {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    } else if sender == phoneNumberMobile2 {
        print("you tapped label \(self.phoneNumberMobile2)")
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(String(describing: mobileCall))") {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    } else if sender == phoneNumberWork2 {
        print("you tapped label \(self.phoneNumberWork2)")
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(String(describing: workCall))") {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    } else {
        print("action failed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a gesture recognizer can't be assigned to more than one view. If you attempt to do so, it will only work on the last view you add it to. You need to create a unique tap gesture for each label. They can each use the same selector.

Next, you are attempting to compare `sender` (which is the gesture) to each of the labels. That won't work. You need to compare `sender.view` to each of the labels.

Last, move `privateCall`, `mobileCall`, and `workCall` within each relevant `if` statement. No need to calculate all three when only one is relevant for a given tap.

Really last, do not use `String(describing:)` to build the URL. Properly unwrap the optional values as needed.

Comment: perfect, i have learnt a lot from this answer.
But still one question: What do you mean with "properly unwrap"?

Comment: I mean "optional binding" using `if let`.